# Line breaks in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want to set cookies capturing page visits, and then give the user the option to click a button and email the content of the cookie. So far I have this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#testButton').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
var oldPathName = $.cookie("currentPath");
var newPathName = window.location.pathname;
var pathCombined = oldPathName+ String.fromCharCode(13)+newPathName;
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 30;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("currentPath", pathCombined, { expires: date });
alert(pathCombined);
 var email = 'me@somewhere.com';
    var subject = 'History';    
    window.location = 'mailto:' + email + '?subject=' + subject + '&body=' +   pathCombined;
});
});
```

This is just a test so far. Clicking the `#testButton` first pops up an alert with the contents of the cookie, then opens up an email with the cookie contents in the body of the mail.

The only problem I’m having is inserting line breaks/carriage returns into the email. I’ve figured out how to get line breaks between the paths into the alert, but it won’t work in the email text.

For example, if I visit two pages, in this order:

```
www.example.com/xxx/yyy/zzz
www.example.com/xxx/yyy/qqq
```

then the alert triggered by the code above displays:

```
/xxx/yyy/zzz
/xxx/yyy/qqq
```

but the body of the email is written as:

```
/xxx/yyy/zzz/xxx/yyy/qqq
```

Formatting the breaks in the email body clearly requires a different way. I tried replacing `String.fromCharCode(13)` with `%0D%0A` but it breaks the JQuery.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `String.fromCharCode(13)` with `'\n'` or `'\\n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to encode the text.

```
var pathCombined = oldPathName+ '\n' +newPathName;

window.location = 'mailto:' 
+ encodeURIComponent(email)
+ '?subject='
+ encodeURIComponent(subject) 
+ '&body=' 
+ encodeURIComponent(pathCombined);
```